# Evaluating a queryset prior to updating

Tags: django, django-queryset

My models store threaded messages that are marked as read/unread.  When a message thread is viewed by a user, unread messages should be displayed as unread and then marked as read in the same request.

Because a queryset is not normally evaluated until it is rendered in the template, my understanding is that I need do this in the following order:

1. Evaluate the messages queryset to retain the message read/unread status in memory
2. Call the update to mark messages as read
3. Render the template using the evaluated queryset

Otherwise, the update will execute first and, when the messages queryset is subsequently evaluated in the template, all messages will be rendered incorrectly as having already been read.

Is the proper way of achieving step 1 to simply to call `list()` on the queryset?

For example:

```
class ViewMessageThread(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'inbox/message_thread.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ViewMessageThread, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        thread = MessageThread.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['thread_id'])
        context['messages'] = list(Message.objects.filter(thread=thread))  # evaluate
        Message.objects.filter(thread=thread).update(status='read')  # update
        return context
```

The [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) contain a warning against evaluating querysets this way because of the memory overhead involved.  I don't expect message threads to contain a large number of messages, and the queryset will be evaluated one way or another (in the view, or in the template).

Is there a different, preferred method of handling this?  Or is this fine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see it fine but I would change one thing: you execute the filter twice. I would do it like this:

```
_query = Message.objects.filter(thread=thread)
context['messages'] = list(_query)
_query.update(status='read')
return context
```

Comment: Incorrect proposal, because only a small part of the expression is the same, without compiling anything to SQL so early before evaluating by `list(queryset)`, the less executing anything. The command `...update(...)` is compiled to a completely different SQL: `UPDATE "yourapp_message" SET "status" = 'read' WHERE "yourapp_message"."thread_id" = %s` and nothing can be spared. Yes, tino's method is the best possible.